# Are there any infinites not from a powerset of the natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

With the cardinality of the natural numbers as $|\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0$ and its powerset as $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})| = 2^{\aleph_0}$, the continuum hypothesis and the axiom of choice says that there is no set such that

$$
\aleph_0 < |S| < 2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1
$$

The whole hierarchy of aleph numbers can be constructed from $\aleph_n = \mathcal{P}(\aleph_{n-1})$. Each aleph is constructed from powerset iterations of the natural numbers. Is there any non-finite set $S$ where this is not true?

$$
|\aleph_0| < |S| \notin \{\aleph_0, \aleph_1, \aleph_2, \ldots  \}
$$

Comment: Sure. Take the union over all natural numbers of the $\aleph_n$. That's new. Then take the powerset and the game starts again.

Comment: $\aleph_{n+1}$ is the _cardinal successor_ of $\aleph_n$.  It is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $\aleph_{n+1} < 2^{\aleph_n} = | \mathcal{P} ( \aleph_n ) |$ for all $n$.  (Heck, its consistent that $\aleph_n < 2^{\aleph_0}$ for all $n$.)

Comment: Reinforcing Arthur's comment: Your understanding of the notation is wrong! $\aleph_1$ is not defined as $2^{\aleph_0}$, it is defined as the smallest cardinal that is greater than $\aleph_0$. The continuum hypothesis is that the two definitions are equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some (valid) points.

1. $\aleph_{n+1}$ is **NOT defined** as $2^{\aleph_n}$. $\aleph_{n+1}$ is the least cardinality of an ordinal which is strictly larger than $\aleph_n$.
2. The continuum hypothesis, if so, is formulated as the assumption $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$. If it is false, then there is an intermediate set of cardinality $\aleph_1$ (assuming the axiom of choice, anyway). It was shown that given any cardinal, the continuum is *consistently* larger. So we can't even decide using the usual axioms of set theory, how many cardinals are between the real numbers and the natural numbers.
3. We can prove, however, that some $\aleph$ numbers cannot be equal to the cardinality of the continuum. For example the first cardinal which is larger than infinitely many [infinite] cardinals, denoted by $\aleph_\omega$, cannot be the cardinality of the continuum.
4. There is, however, another hierarchy, of $\beth$ [read: Beth] numbers ($\aleph$ is the first letter of the Hebrew alphabet, and $\beth$ is the second letter). It is defined as $\beth_0=\aleph_0$ and $\beth_{\alpha+1}=2^{\beth_\alpha}$ (I'm omitting the limit stages, for now).

   In terms of $\beth$ numbers we can in fact prove that $2^{\aleph_0}=\beth_1$, and the continuum hypothesis can now be stated as $\aleph_1=\beth_1$.
5. Now your question can be rewritten as either of two questions. If we change the occurrences of $\aleph$ to $\beth$, then every $\beth$ number is defined as a power set of the previous one (and I am omitting the limit case, again); and so the answer is "no, there isn't any", or we can what are the $\aleph$ numbers which are smaller than $\beth_1$, but as I pointed out, we can show that this is consistently any possible value $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer, I think it clears up a few mistakes in both my nomenclature and my understanding of the ordinals. I was trying to lookup the Hebrew "B" transfinite number and couldn't simply google for the letter: to help those who follow, they are called [Beth numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number).