# What is cardinal of set of all Cauchy sequences?

Tags: cardinals, real-numbers

Here are basically two questions. The first, what is the cardinal of equivalent Cauchy sequences of rationals? I know it's $\beth_1$ because of the set is essentially real numbers. But I want to know how to obtain this in view of Cauchy sequences, instead of decimal expansions. I mean, how to construct a one-to-one mapping from equivalent sequences to subsets of integers? Furthermore, what's the cardinal of Cauchy sequences? Is that ${\beth_1}^{\beth_0}=\beth_1$?

**Edit**

Thanks all commentators for indicating the error sourced from absence of (generalized) continuum hypothesis. Now my problem becomes asking for an explicit mapping from set of equivalent Cauchy sequences to power set of integers without computation of cardinals.

Comment: Actually, it's $\beth_1$, not $\aleph_1$. $\beth_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$, and this only equals $\aleph_1$ if the "continuum hypothesis" holds, which is something independent of the usual (ZFC) axioms of set theory.

Comment: @mike4ty4 Did I see somewhere that "continuum hypothesis" cannot be proved nor be disproved? Then what are $\beth_0$ and $\aleph_1$?

Comment: The cardinality of the set of all Cauchy sequences is the cardinality $c$ of the continuum. The cardinality of any equivalence class is also the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks, but could you explain in detail

Comment: $\beth_0$ is $\aleph_0$, the size of the natural numbers. $\beth_1$ is $\mathfrak c$, the size of power set of the natural numbers, and the size of the reals. [$\aleph_1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number) is (the size of) $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal, and the collection of countable ordinals.

Comment: In addition, you do not prove $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ in ZFC (if ZFC is consistent.) Continuum hyphothesis implies $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ in ZFC. However, it is consistent with ZFC that $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$.

Comment: Take the Cauchy sequence $1,1/2,1/4,\dots$ converging to $0$. We can modify it by choosing $a_i$ arbitrarily in the interval $(1/2^i,1/2^{i+1})$. There are at least countably many choices, even if we confine ourselves to rationals. Thus there are at least $\omega^\omega$ Cauchy sequences of rationals that converge to $0$. And since there are $c^\omega=c$ *sequences*, the results follow.

Comment: @tetori I'm not so familiar with these, say ${\aleph_1}^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$. Could you recommend some books?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo So you mean there's no difference between $\aleph_0$ and $\beth_0$? Actually I didn't find $\beth$ in my logic lesson.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks, that's my deduction for any Cauchy sequences. But that's your for equivalent Cauchy sequences. So these two cardinals consistent?

Comment: Do you mean that you were taught that the cardinality of the real numbers is $\aleph_1$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the cardinality of all sequences with coefficients in an infinite set?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/whats-the-cardinality-of-all-sequences-with-coefficients-in-an-infinite-set)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was taught that is $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$

Comment: Then you were taught wrong. See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668990/continuum-and-aleph-one) and also [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666469/are-there-any-infinites-not-from-a-powerset-of-the-natural-numbers).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you very much. I got that. Is there any recommendation for relative books?

Answer (score 2):

The set of all sequences rational numbers is $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$, and it's cardinality is 
$$|\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|\leq|\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N}|=|\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})|=|\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})|,$$
where $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is the power set of $\mathbb{N}$. In other words:

Take two injections $\phi:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ and $\psi:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ (you can construct these explicitly, using the well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$). Then the function $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ given by
$$\varphi(f)=\psi\left(\left\{(n,\phi(f(n))):n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\right)$$
is injective, hence so is its restricition to the Cauchy sequences.

Comment: It seems your $\Psi$ is a mapping to integers

Comment: @zhangwfjh See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54158/the-cartesian-product-mathbbn-times-mathbbn-is-countable). I just want to use the fact that $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable.